# Reading text file and inputting into double array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

Hi for my HW I am suppose to read a text file of '.' and 'x' representing cells in Conway's Game of Life. I'm having trouble with reading the given text input and adding it into my double integer arrays. Specifically the rowcounter and columncounter part I'm sure there is a better way to do it but when I tried for loops it only read one row. I included previous parts of the code just in case. Thanks.

```java
// Initiate file
File inputfile = new File(inputfilename);
try {
    input = new Scanner(inputfile);
} catch (Exception ie) {
}

// Get array size
int[] arraysize = new int[2];
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int token = input.nextInt();
        arraysize[i] = token;
    }
}
//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraysize));

// Create Array
int[][] newarray = new int[arraysize[0]][arraysize[1]];
//System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newarray));

// Read initial
int rowcounter = 0;
int columncounter = 0;
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner inputtoken = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
    while (inputtoken.hasNext()) {
        String token = inputtoken.next();
        //System.out.print(token);
        char xchar = token.charAt(0);
        if (xchar == 'x') {
            newarray[rowcounter][columncounter] = 1;
        } else {
            newarray[rowcounter][columncounter] = 0;
            //System.out.print(rowcounter);
        }
        columncounter = columncounter + 1;
        //System.out.print(columncounter);
    }
    columncounter = 0;
    System.out.println();
    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1;
    //System.out.print(rowcounter);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newarray));
```

Comment: I think the only thing you're missing is resetting `columncounter` after reading a whole row. Btw. in the lines where you assing values to the array in one case you have `rowcounter` and in the other `rowcounter-1` - don't think that's intended.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I changed it to rowcounter and resetted the columncounter before my System.out.println statement. It's giving me the Index 10 out of bounds for length 10. Am I adding an extra rowcounter?